# Swift: How to take input from solid button through earphone jack?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on an app and I need it to take input from two solid buttons connected from the earphone jack. I need the app to count how much time it take to finish pressing the button 10 times. I have the timer working now but I can't figure out how to make it take the input. Also, if I have this figured out, is there a way to stimulate? Can you guys give me a hand, please?

Comment: Button basically toggle the state of line, so you have to monitor in change of state line.

Comment: There will a event associated with the press of button.

Comment: @GaneshK I just started coding and I don't have much idea about what you're saying. Can you please share more details with me?

Comment: @garyma705 did you solve your problem ?

Comment: @VarunNaharia No, I'm still struggling with this. The solution you provided gave me some idea. But I just started learning Swift and there are too many things I haven't figure out yet. So right now I'm trying to catch up with the basics and I will try your way when everything makes more sense to me. Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

remoteControlReceivedWithEvent is used get the audio controls (play/pause), probably it's same as your audio jack device. You need to enable your application with Background audio capability and should add code to start audio session for your app so that you can get call backs when any button pressed in headphones to the function

try this:

```
override func remoteControlReceivedWithEvent(event: UIEvent?) {
        let rc = event!.subtype
        print("does this work? \(rc.rawValue)")
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried putting this in my code but nothing is happening. I'm a beginner in coding. Can you please give me more details on how to make this work?

Comment: remoteControlReceivedWithEvent is used get the audio controls (play/pause), probably it's same as your audio jack device

Comment: You need to enable your application with Background audio capability and should add code to start audio session for your app so that you can get call backs when any button pressed in headphones to the function mentioned in answer